# Class type in System Verilog which can not be constructed and extended as sub class

Tags: oop, abstract-class, subclass, system-verilog

I have created System Verilog class with Virtual keyword.
After adding virtual keyword as prefix to class abc, it becomes abstract class for which object can not be created using new() constructor.If do so user gets compilation error.

virtual class abc;
........
endclass

But at the same time no other class can be extended from class abc as sub class. i.e. class abc can not be extended into a sub class.

Does SV supports any such class type that can not be created using new() constructor(like abstract class) and can not be extended to a subclass.
If system verilog supports any such class type, in what scenario it will be helpful to define this class.

Any input will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect about a not being able to extend a virtual/abstract class. You *must* extend it order to construct it as a derived subclass. You will get an error if you try to construct a virtual class.

SystemVerilog has no mechanism that prevents you from *extending* any class, but it does have a way from preventing you from *constructing* any extension of a class by declaring the constructor as `local`. If you do this, you must provide some other static method to call the local constructor. This is typicaly used in what's called the *singleton pattern*.

```
class A;
  local function new;
  endfunction 
  local static A singleton;
  static function A get;
    if (singleton == null)
       singleton = new;
    return singleton;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Now the `A`'s constructor can only be called once, and you cannot construct an extended subclass of `A`.It's constructor would need to call super.new() and that has been made illegal.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59 for clarifying,I was looking for local function new, but was not able to put query into words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to use the class only for `static` methods.

As @dave_59 already said, you can declare the constructor `local`:

```
class some_class;

  local function new();
    // intentionally empty
  endfunction

endclass
```

This will cause a compile error when you try to instantiate it:

```
some_class obj = new(); // leads to compile error
```

It will also cause a compile error if you extend the class. This is because any sub-class will implicitly call `super.new()`, which is illegal, because `super.new` is `local`:

```
class some_subclass extends some_class;

  // even if we don't explicitly declare a constructor, the following is added
  // automatically
  //
  // function new();
  //   super.new();  // leads to compile error
  // endfunction

endclass
```

Comment: Thanks Tudor Timi for clarifying working of local function new in base class and illegal super.new() in it's extended class.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you mean. Yes, you can declare an abstract (virtual) class, you can extend it into any other class. Why did you say that you cannot?

Here is a quick example:

```
virtual class X;
  function new();
  endfunction

  function print();
    $display("hello world");
  endfunction

endclass

class Y extends X;
endclass

module A();
  Y y;
  X x;
  initial begin
    y = new();
    x = y;
    x.print();
  end
  
endmodule
```

`Y` is a derived class and you can easy do that by extending class `X`

Comment: In Posted query I wanted to understand, Is it possible in SV,user declare a class, created object for only one time, when tried to extend it into any subclass gets an error. dave_59 and Tudor Timi answered and clarified my understanding of local function new & its use. Thanks for the input @Serge